# Firebase Securing Nodes in the Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I use Firebase. Here is what one of my nodes looks like:

```
--Users
----RandomUID1
----RandomUID2
----RandomUID3
```

For Rules, this is what I have:

```
--"users" : {

----".read": "auth != null && !root.child('blockedUsers').hasChild(auth.uid)",

----".write": "auth != null && !root.child('blockedUsers').hasChild(auth.uid)"

--}
```

What I would like is for reading from the `users` node to stay the same, but I would like for writing to only be allowed on children of the `users` node. The reason for this is it would be catastrophic if I accidentally wrote code one night that deleted the entire `users` node. Is it possible to make a rule so that writing on the node itself is not allowed but writing to child nodes is allowed?

Is there a way to secure myself from such an accident that might occur because of human error?

Answer (score 2):

You can use variables, [Firebase variable rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#using_variables_to_capture_path_segments)

.At the users node i didn't add a write rule, which doesn't allow for data modification.

```
 "users":{
      ".read": "auth != null && !root.child('blockedUsers').hasChild(auth.uid)",
      "$uid": { //where $uid is child
        ".read": "auth!==null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": ""auth!==null && auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! what if I put "write": "false" at the users node?

Comment: That won't make any difference here, since the default is `false`. But you may want to add it for clarity and then specify a more relaxed rule on a lower level. One important thing to remember is that the inverse is not possible. Permission is inherited: so once you specify `true` on one level, you cannot take that permission away on a lower level.

Comment: Good answer btw @Fowotade